# java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'gender' at row 1 for enum

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, annotations

I am using annotations to persist the record in MySQL database.

at the database side I am defining column gender as gender ENUM('M','F')

Defining enum as follows :

```
public enum Gender {
M,F;
}
```

In the annotation class I am defining enum property as follows :

```
@Column(name="gender")
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) 
private Enum<Gender> gender=Gender.M;
```

I am saving the property in the database as follows :

```
employee.setGender(Gender.M);
```

But when am running the program am getting following error :

```
Hibernate: insert into Employees (birth_date, first_name,gender,hire_date,last_nane values
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Data truncated for column 'gender' at row 1
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert         
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation    
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract   
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert  
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)

at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2345)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2330)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation
... 25 more
```

I tried with both String as well as ordinal but error remain as it is.

Ordinal means int.Do I need to change schema definition of gender type from enum to String or int.
Do hibernate annotation do not work with column type enum?
Please help me regarding the issue.

Comment: I wrote a question about your enum declaration because is strange to see it. If you want point your browser to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25114306/difference-between-declare-variable-as-enumenumtype-and-enumtype/25114411#25114404

Comment: Have you got your answer? I got the same error and can't find the solution except to change datatype of that variable to String instead of enum

Answer (score 2):

What `Enum<Gender>`? `Gender` is already an `Enum` and this type of declaration is not what you want.
Try a more easy:

```
@Column(name="gender")
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL) 
private Gender gender=Gender.M;
```

Comment: Enum<gender> is to specify which enum am using to persist.

Comment: am tried with what you suggested but I got warning to specify the enum type. Also the error does not disappear. But thanks for the suggestion Luca.

Comment: Gender IS an enum so you don't need to specify, but apart this, in MySQL - if I'm not wrong - ENUMs are treated as String and not number so ORDINAL should be wrong. I think is preferable to move to byte/int standard SQL type and not ENUM proprietary.

Comment: IMHO the best choice is to move to a numeric SQL datatype to avoid any unwanted conversion done implicitly by RDMBS

Comment: I mean: instead of using a MYSQL ENUM custom type use a standard int/byte type for gender field

Answer (score 0):

I went through the exact same problem recently, where gender was an `enum` of two characters in my database.

The problem came from the encoding of characters being different between Java and Mysql (UTF-16 and UTF-8). Placing a `String` of exactly one character instead of a `char` solved the problem for me.

Since it doesn't for you, you also might want to add `jdbcCompliantTruncation=false` to your connection url (such as: `jdbc:mysql://yourserver:3306/yourdatabase?jdbcCompliantTruncation=false`). It should stop the driver from generating an exception at this warning. It didn't help me personally, but it may be worth a try.