# Difference between declare variable as Enum<EnumType> and EnumType

Tags: java, enums

I got inspiration from [java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'gender' at row 1 for enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25113293/java-sql-sqlexception-data-truncated-for-column-gender-at-row-1-for-enum/25113349?noredirect=1#comment39083500_25113349).
I have this enum

```
public enum MyEnum {
  Value1,
  Value2;
}
```

and this sample code:

```
MyEnum raw = MyEnum.Value1;
Enum<MyEnum> wrapped = MyEnum.Value1;
```

1. `System.out.println(raw);`
2. `System.out.println(wrapped);`
3. `System.out.println(raw.getDeclaringClass());`
4. `System.out.println(wrapped.getDeclaringClass());`
5. `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(raw.values()));`
6. `System.out.println(wrapped.values());`
7. `System.out.println(raw.equals(wrapped));`
8. `System.out.println(wrapped.equals(raw));`

And for

- *Points 1-2, 3-4*: return the same result
- *Point 5*: return [Value1, Value2] (but should be accessed in a static way to be correct)
- *Point 6*: Compile error: undefined for type `Enum<MyEnum>`. In order to get it works I have place a cast as `System.out.println(((MyEnum) wrapped).values());`
- *Point 7*: Return `true`
- *Point 8*: Return `true`

In addiction, checking with a debugger, variables share are the same object (same object id).
Which are the differences between two types of declaration?

Comment: What is the idea behind using `Enum<MyEnum>`?

Comment: That's what I wrote to the person who wrote the question from which I took inspiration. But this type of declaration is so strange for me so I asked if the are any particular differences and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is quite simple: it’s the same as the difference between

```
String foo="bla";
```

and

```
Object foo="bla";
```

---

`Enum<MyEnum>` is the superclass of `MyEnum`. So when using the superclass, methods already defined in the superclass are available but methods defined in the specific subclass are not available without the type cast. When invoking instance methods which have been overridden in the specific `enum` class, the subclass method is invoked, as always with Java.

Using `Enum<MyEnum>` makes not much sense. Using `E extends Enum<E>` however is a construct used by Generic code being able to deal with arbitrary `enum`s. Like `EnumMap` or `EnumSet`.

Answer (score 1):

> Which are the differences between two types of declaration?

`MyEnum extends Enum<MyEnum>` so the object is going to be exactly the same, only the type of the reference is different.

Comment: I think your assumption is correct because I think any `enum EnumType` class declaration extends `Enum<EnumType>` or I am wrong?

Comment: Yes, It does implicitly, which I would know if I could see the code. ;)

Comment: I accepted @Holger answer because explains well the question about `MyEnum extends Enum<MyEnum>` but your answer also hit the target and upvoting seems the right choice.